# hide and show tableviewcell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, button

1.I have a button to control the cell height
After press the button I want to change indexPath.row == 1 height to 44
press again to height to 0

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1 {
        return 0
    }
    return 44
}
```

2.I have a button in tableViewCell
press the button can change the parents's view's constraint

**I want to get language.identifier in tableViewCell**

[image: I want to get language.identifier in tableViewCell]

Comment: 1. Total, How many rows u having? 2. This means ? change the parents's view's constraint ??

Comment: 1. Just two rows 2. I want to get language.identifier in tableViewCell, left photo 37-38

Comment: Possible, show ur screenshot, how the design will be ?

Comment: How the screen should be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first question try this:

1. create a `Bool` variable and set it at the top of your class as a global variable.
2. In your button's action, change the variable's current value and then apply `tableView.reloadData()`
3. Check the current value of the bool in the `heightForRow` func and set the height accordingly.

Something like this:

```
var isHeightZero = true

@IBAction func toggleHeight(_ sender: UIButton) {
    isHeightZero = !isHeightZero
    tableView.reloadData()
} 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1 {
        if isHeightZero {
            return 0
        } else {
            return 44
        }
    }
    return 44
}
```

Comment: Thank You. It's Working Now !!

Comment: @user9320514 pleasure. buddy. If you don't mind, mark my answer as the correct answer ;).